# end parent tag in mixed content

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying figure out in XSL how to end element <bold>  it the parent of  element

**EDIT** Also, content of element <paragraph>  and  <bold> gets a <style name 
="bold">. excluding the content of  <link> element.  <style> will wrapped within the content of  <paragraph>  and  <bold>.  Also content of element  <paragraph> can have one or more   <bold>  and <link>

**Input XML**

```
<paragraph>
     This is some text that  has no style
 </paragraph> 

 <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>correct way</bold> <link>need    
     to be linked </link> to a document
 </paragraph>

 <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>incorrect <link>need
     to be linked </link> way </bold> to a document
 </paragraph>
```

**Output Xml** should be

```
<paragraph>
     This is some text that  has no style
 </paragraph> 

 <paragraph>
     <style name="bold">This is some text that is  <bold>correct way</bold></style>
     <link>need to be linked </link>
     <style name="bold"> to a document</style>
 </paragraph>

 <paragraph>
     <style name="bold">This is some text that is  <bold>incorrect</bold></style> 
     <link>need to be linked </link>
     <style name="bold"><bold> way </bold> to a document</style>
 </paragraph>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bold[link]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bold[link]/text()">
  <bold><xsl:value-of select="."/></bold>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
 <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>correct way</bold> <link>need
     to be linked </link> to a document
 </paragraph>

 <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>incorrect <link>need
     to be linked </link> way </bold> to a document
 </paragraph>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>correct way</bold>
      <link>need
     to be linked </link> to a document
 </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>incorrect </bold>
      <link>need
     to be linked </link>
      <bold> way </bold> to a document
 </paragraph>
</t>
```

---

**The OP updated the question -- here is the slightly modified transformation that implements the initial + new requirements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="paragraph[bold]">
  <paragraph>
    <style name="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></style>
  </paragraph>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bold[link]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bold[link]/text()">
  <bold><xsl:value-of select="."/></bold>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following document:**

```
<t>
<paragraph>
     This is some text that  has no style
 </paragraph>

 <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>correct way</bold> <link>need
     to be linked </link> to a document
 </paragraph>

 <paragraph>
     This is some text that is  <bold>incorrect <link>need
     to be linked </link> way </bold> to a document
 </paragraph>
 </t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <paragraph>
     This is some text that  has no style
 </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
      <style name="bold">
     This is some text that is  <bold>correct way</bold>
         <link>need
     to be linked </link> to a document
 </style>
   </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
      <style name="bold">
     This is some text that is  <bold>incorrect </bold>
         <link>need
     to be linked </link>
         <bold> way </bold> to a document
 </style>
   </paragraph>
</t>
```

Comment: Thanks again. LINK element should not be wrapped between STYLE element. PARAGRAPH element should have STYLE element within content of PARAGRAPH and BOLD element but NOT LINK element

Comment: @user2204573, Could you, please, *edit* the question and explain the requirements? I am confused.